# Spring security POST login sets already expired session

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jetty

I am trying to secure a REST service I have implemented.

```
http://localhost:8080/api/**
```

needs to be secured.

Running this command:

```
   curl -i -X POST -d j_username=user -d j_password=user http://localhost:8089/spring-security-rest/j_spring_security_check
```

results in this output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1ccuzrzlpamjb9ce47savvlsx;Path=/
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(7.6.5.v20120716)
```

where the cookie is already expired upon its creation. Any idea why this is happening?

*applicationContext-security.xml*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

<http entry-point-ref="restAuthEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>

    <form-login
        authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="myFailureHandler"
    />

    <logout />
</http>

<beans:bean id="restAuthEntryPoint"
    class="com.example.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
<beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler"
    class="com.example.security.MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
<beans:bean id="myFailureHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="temporary" password="temporary" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    </beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default cookie behaviour implementing your own PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices filter in the chain.

Comment: Why would the default behavior set the cookie expiration date to 1970 though?

Comment: That question I don´t know because the Spring implementation to cookies behaviour is abstract to us. The only documentation about this is here, and is not sufficient. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html